Generate Invoice using Stripe API
Is there any way in Stripe to set the next invoice date while creating an invoice without a subscription, so that invoices can be generated on a recurring basis?

If you're looking to create invoices in the future, I think you can use the effective_at parameter when creating the invoice. But if your use-case is a recurring invoice generation, why don't you want to use Stripe's subscriptions?
